# MySQL Substring with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring, date-format

I've searched over the internet but couldn't find a way to resolve my issue. My query is something like that

```
SELECT users.id, SUBSTRING(posts.datestr, 4, 8) 
FROM users, posts 
WHERE posts.datestr='Jan-2014'
```

(That query above was shortened)

The value in posts.datestr is actually `20-Jan-2014`, but I want it to be `Jan-2014` instead, but even after adding that `SUBSTRING` code, it still somehow shows as `20-Jan-2014`.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is datestr is varchar? if yes, why you are not using as data type?

Comment: try  this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2014 AND MONTH(Date) = 1"`

Comment: My datestr is a varchar, would that still work?

Comment: Really, convert the data and the column to `DATE` datatype and your problems will be much easier, trivial to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alias the result of the `SUBSTRING` and use that alias in your conditions (`shortdate` in the example below)

Since you'll now be using an alias in your conditions, you can't use the `where` clause, you can though use the `having` clause

something like:

```
SELECT users.id, SUBSTRING(posts.datestr, 4, 8) as shortdate 
FROM users, posts 
HAVING shortdate='Jan-2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, SUBSTRING(posts.datestr, 4, 8) shortpostdate FROM users, posts WHERE shortpostdate='Jan-2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Inner JOIN`

```
SELECT users.id, SUBSTRING(posts.datestr, 4, 8) FROM users inner join posts on users.userid = posts.[primary key] WHERE posts.datestr='Jan-2014'
```

Below Link can help you http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

use the below

```
substr(posts.datestr,3)
```

instead of

```
 SUBSTRING(posts.datestr, 4, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**DATETIME**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function instead of **SUBSTRING()**

```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(posts.datestr, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%b-%Y') updatedDate
FROM users, posts 
HAVING updatedDate = 'Jan-2014'
```